# How Can a Data Access Object (DAO) Allow Simultaneous Updates to a Subset of Columns?

Tags: oop, coldfusion, javabeans, dao

*Please forgive me if I misuse any OOP terminology as I'm still getting my feet wet on the subject.*

I've been reading up on object oriented programming (OOP) - specifically for web applications.  I have been going over the concept of a data access object (DAO). The DAO is responsible for CRUD (Create, Read, Update, and Delete) methods and connecting your application's service (business logic) layer to the database.

My question specifically pertains to the `Update()` method within a DAO.  In the examples I've read about, developers typically pass a bean object into the DAO `update()` method as its main argument `updateCustomer(customerBean)` The method then executes some SQL which updates all of the columns based on the data in the bean.

The problem I see with this logic is that the `update()` method updates **ALL** columns within the database based on the bean's data and could theoretically cause it to overwrite columns another user or system might need to update simultaneously.

A simplified example might be:

- User 1 updates field A in the bean
- User 2 updates field B in the bean
- User 2 passes bean to DAO, DAO updates all fields.
- User 1 passes bean to DAO, DAO updates all fields.
- User 2's changes have been lost!

I've read about *Optimistic Locking* and *Pessimistic Locking* as possible solutions for only allowing one update at a time but I can think of many cases where an application *needs* to allow for editing different parts of a record at the same time without locking or throwing an error.

For example, lets say an administrator is updating a customer's `lastName` at the same time the customer logs into the web site and the login system needs to update the `dateLastLoggedIn` column while simultaneously a scheduled task needs to update a `lastPaymentReminderDate`.  In this crazy example, if you were passing a bean object to the `update()` method and saving the entire record of data each time its possible that whichever process runs the `update()` method last would overwrite all of the data.

Surely there must be a way to solve this.  I've come up with a few possibilities based on my research but I would be curious to know the proper/best way to accomplish this.

**Possible solution 1: DAO `Update()` Method Does Not Accept Bean as Argument**

If the `update()` method accepted a structure of data containing all of the columns in the database that need updating instead of a bean object you could make your SQL statement smart enough to only update the fields that were passed to the method.  For example, the argument might look like this:

`{
    customerID: 1,
    firstName: 'John'
}`

This would basically tell the `update()` method to only update the column `firstName` based on the `customerID`, 1.  This would make your DAO extremely flexible and would give the service layer the ability to dynamically interact with the database. I have a gut feeling that this violates some "golden rule" of OOP but I'm not sure which. I've also never seen any examples online of a DAO behaving like this.

**Possible Solution 2: Add additional `update()` methods to your DAO.**

You could also solve this by adding more specific `update()` methods to your DAO. For example you might have one for `dateLastLoggedIn()' and 'dateLastPaymentReminderDate()`.  This way each service that needs to update the record could theoretically do so simultaneously. Any locking could be done for each specific update method if needed.

The main downside of this approach is that your DAO will start to get pretty muddy with all kinds of update statements and I've seen many blog posts writing about how messy DAOs can quickly become.

How would you solve this type of conundrum with DAO objects assuming you need to allow for updating subsets of record data simultaneously? Would you stick with passing a bean to the DAO or is there some other solution I haven't considered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do a DAO.read() operation that returns a bean, then update the bean with the user's new values, then pass that bean to the DAO.update(bean) method, then you shouldn't have a problem unless the two user operations happen within milliseconds of each other.  Your question implies that the beans are being stored in the session scope or something like that before passed to the update() method.  If that's what you're doing, don't, for exactly the reasons you described.  You don't want your bean getting out of sync with the db record.  For even better security, wrap a transaction around the read and update operations, then there'd be no way the two users could step on each other's toes, even if user2 submits his changes at the exact same time as user 1.

Read(), set values, update() is the way to go, I think.  Keep the beans fresh.  Nobody wants stale beans.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Dave Anderson. My question actually pertains to solving the DAO.update(bean) problem when two users (or a user and a service) need to update the record potentially at the same time. The example was supposed to demonstrate a typical web site scenario.  The bean only exists during the request scope and should be saved when the user POSTs data back to the server. The requests might occur at different times but both POSTs could theoretically be made at the same time and thus one user could overwrite the other.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Yeah, and I think I addressed that concern.  If you wrap a transaction around the read/set properties/update sequence of events, then you won't encounter a problem.  If two users update a record at the same time, the transaction will prevent the scenario you describe, preventing a dirty record from getting updated. 

transaction {
  read();
  set properties;
  update();
  commit();
}

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense. A transaction/lock will be helpful in preventing dirty data from being added into the database. However, what if you do want two users or systems to be able to update the database at the same time? For example, user 1 is updating Column A, and user 2 is updating Column B? If I use a transaction/lock, I won't be able to update the record simultaneously right?

Comment: Correct.  The table is 'locked' until the transaction is complete, then the next transaction executes.  If the transaction includes both a read and an update, you're safe.

Comment: Hi @Dave L, in technical OO terms, you should not require user 1 and user 2 to, respectively, update column A and column B simultaneously. The columns correspond to properties that define the state of an object. After user 1 updates column A, the object generated from the bean has state A, say. When user 2 updates column B, there is a change of state. The transaction/lock is therefore necessary.